# A new iMac will come with a 32 bit or 64 bit OS preinstalled?

Tags: macos, mac, 64-bit

Will a newly purchased iMac come with a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snow leopard runs 64 bit on Intel CPUs (PPC processors are no longer supporte), so a new iMac will run the operating system in 64bit mode.  Applications will run with 64bit too if there is a 64 bit version, otherwise of course 32 bit software runs fine too.

Comment: It's far more complicated than that: the OS will be installed with "universal" 32/64-bit binaries, but the kernel will actually run in 32-bit mode (for driver compatibility).  Apps will generally run in 64-bit mode if the CPU supports it, which the current iMacs do (some earlier Intel Macs didn't).

Comment: In other words, "Yes".

Answer (score 4):

The kernel will still be 32-bit unless you tweak your configuration.

Rest of the system (applications, services, …) is fully 64-bit (except iTunes for the moment).